# Setting heading colors in AppCompat Theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to figure out how to set the color for the headings in my `PreferenceFragment` which uses the new `AppCompat` theme. An screenshot of my settings `Fragment`, which `extends` `PreferenceFragment`, is shown below:

[image]

I can set the color of the `ActionBar` by using the `colorPrimary` attribute, and the colors of the primary and secondary text by using `android:textColor` and `android:textColorSecondary` attributes, respectively. However, I cannot figure out how to set the color of the headings - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you getting Lollipop style preferences on KitKat, while using a PreferenceFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally figured out that the headings in a `PreferenceFragment` can be changed by using the `colorAccent` attribute. Also, since it is an AppCompat theme, Android needs to be removed from the namespace:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_grey_500</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Im using this (you can remove .Inverse too):

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead.Inverse"
```

In my header Im using the colorAccent, then:

```
android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
```

All my TextView:

```
       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAdvancedSetting"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Advanced Settings"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead.Inverse"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

And an image of it (jellybean, kitkat and lollipop), black border is is the emulator:

[image]